# Problems with apache2 and virtualHosts

Tags: apache2, symfony-1.4, virtualhost

I am trying to set up a virtual host at localhost. I am installing symfony 1.4 on my ubuntu 12.04 LTS, but I got some problems.

I installed apache2, php5 and mySql. Localhost works so I assume that apache it's ok.

You can found symfony installation and configuration instructions [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_4/en/05-Web-Server-Configuration).

After several days these are my configuration files:

http.conf:

```
ServerName 127.0.0.1
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/test:

```
# Be sure to only have this line once in your configuration
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080

# This is the configuration for your project
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  DocumentRoot "/home/user/test/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/home/user/test/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf /home/user/test/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/home/user/test/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and localhost:8080 doesn't works.

UPDATE: 
Ok, after several modifications my httpd.conf is the same:

```
ServerName 127.0.0.1
```

And my /etc/apache2/sites-available/test:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  DocumentRoot "/home/user/test/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/home/user/test/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf /home/user/test/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/home/user/test/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does your apache run on port 80 or 8080? (check `ports.conf`)

Comment: Have you tried giving physical path to all directories? Everyting else seems ok.

Comment: @j0k I run apache on port 80. `NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80`

Comment: @qais I don't understand you... Could you give me an example?

Comment: i mean like this: <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  DocumentRoot "c:/project/test/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "c:/project/test/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf c:/project/test/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "c:/project/test/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 1):

If Apache use the port 80, remove this line in your conf:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Then replace all `8080` by `80` and try `http://localhost`. It should work.

**edit:**

Regarding the error `could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:80 no listening sockets available`, it seems you have an other server listening on the port 80.

Maybe it's a better idea to come back on the 8080 port (on the `httpd.conf`) and then update the `ports.conf` to set :

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
Listen 8080
```

If you don't have a `ports.conf` file, find `Listen` in your main configuration file and do the update.

Comment: After every change, do I have to add my site to sites-enabled with the command a2ensite?

Comment: No. But you need to restart Apache.

Comment: Ok, I just noticed that both are the same file. Now, when I restart my apache I got this message: "Restarting web server apache2 [Sat Jun 16 12:31:00 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts [Sat Jun 16 12:31:00 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
"

Answer (score 0):

Verify you have your site test into `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`. if not do:

```
sudo a2ensite test
```

This command will enable the site `test`. Remember to restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

Error message.

(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down Unable to open logs

It can be solved by commenting out the line Listen 80 in your httpd.conf file.

Regards
Rajkiran